# Algorithm to find 'maximal' independent set in a simple graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

in words, can someone post directions towards finding the 'maximal' independent set in a simple graph?

I read up something from ETH site which said one can find such in O(n) by simply picking a random vertex v and than scanning the rest and attempting to find if there's an edge from v to the rest.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, by definition, a maximal indpendent set is an independent set to which no more vertices can be added without violating the 'independence' condition.

So just picking vertices till you can pick no more would give you a maximal independent set, can be done in linear time (i.e. linear in |V| + |E|).

Note, this is different from *maximum* independent set, which is an independent set of the largest possible size and finding that is NP-Hard.

Comment: But that's O(m^2), where m is the size of the independent set you find. For a graph with very few edges, that is close to O(n^2).

Comment: It is linear in number of edges. In graph problems, the representation matters and linear usually means |V| + |E|. Technically speaking, size of input could be larger than |V| + |E|. Sorry if that was not clear. I will edit the answer.

Comment: NP-Hard, does that mean there is no pseudo P solution either?

Comment: @Thomas. No, even subset sum problem is NP-Hard which has pseudo P solutions. NP-Hard = at least as hard as any problem in NP. It has got nothing to do with pseudo P solutions. If that problem is also in NP, then it becomes NP-Complete. I wasn't sure if this was in NP, so didn't mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Found this on the web, probably from a class" **To accompany the text ``Introduction to Parallel Computing'', Addison Wesley, 2003**

Finding a Maximal Independent Set (MIS)

```
parallel MIS algorithms use randimization to gain
concurrency (Luby's algorithm for graph coloring).

Initially, each node is in the candidate set C. Each
node generates a (unique) random number and
communicates it to its neighbors.

If a nodes number exceeds that of all its neighbors, it
joins set I. All of its neighbors are removed from C.

This process continues until C is empty.

On average, this algorithm converges after O(log|V|)
such steps.
```